# importing class from another file gives error when working and no error when not working

Tags: python, import, python-module

I am attempting to import a class named MainMenus from this file

```
B:\Programming\Python\RaceDash\src\UIModules\Menus.py
```

here is the code for the class

```
class MainMenus:
    def StartUp():
        #do stuff
    def MainMenu():
        #doing other stuff
```

I also have the _*init*_.py file in this path

```
B:\Programming\Python\RaceDash\src\UIModules\__init__.py
```

my main python file is here

```
B:\Programming\Python\RaceDash\src\Main.Py
```

and looks like this

```
from .UIModules.Menus import MainMenus

def Main():

    MainMenus.StartUp()

    while True:
        MainMenus.MainMenu()
        userSelect = input(": ")

Main()
```

pylance gives no errors when but when I attempt to run the program I get this error:

```
ile "b:\Programming\Python\RaceDash\src\Main.Py", line 1, in <module>
from .UIModules.Menus import MainMenus
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

When I remove the leading period pylance shows this error

```
Import "UIModules.Menus" could not be resolved
```

The application runs fine but I lose intellisense for any function from the other class.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the package folder to a directory that is already in PATH

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:B:\Programming\Python\RaceDash\src\
python3 Main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved by going to the folder of my program and changing the extension. My file were not register as py file because I have created them in my VScode folder.